# How to set keyboard off at beginning on React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, keyboard, styles, mobile-application

My app at first opening direct a login page and keyboard open automaticly! But what i want is keyboard off position at beginning but when clicking any input must be keyboard on.Here is my login.js page

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Formik } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import Axios from 'axios';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';



import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  ActivityIndicator,
  

} from 'react-native';
import { Container, Header, Content, Form, Item, Input, Button } from 'native-base';
import { set } from 'react-native-reanimated';

export default class Login extends Component {

  render() {

    return (



      <ScrollView contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic" >
      
        <View style={styles.containerx}>
          <Container style={styles.bigContainer} >


            <Content contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', padding: 30 }}>
              <Image
                source={ require('../assets/icon1024.png') }
                style={{ width: 150, height: 150, alignSelf: 'center', marginBottom: 10 }}
              />

              <Text style={styles.loginText}>KUŞ SOR</Text>
              <Text style={[styles.loginText, { fontSize: 14 }]} >Birdpx Kuş Tanımlama Platformu</Text>
              {
                this.state.loading == true ? <View style={styles.emptyCont}><ActivityIndicator size='large' color='white' /></View> :
                  <Formik
                    initialValues={{username: '', password: ''}}
                    onSubmit={this._handleSubmit}
                    validationSchema={
                      Yup.object().shape({
                        password: Yup.string().min(6, 'Minimim 6 Karakter').required('Bu Alan Zorunludur'),
                        username: Yup.string().required('Bu Alan Zorunludur'),

                      })
                    }
                  >
                    {({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values, errors }) => (
                      <Form>

                        <Item>
                          <Input
                             onChangeText={handleChange('username')}
                             onBlur={handleBlur('username')}
                            placeholder="Kullanıcı Adı"
                            style={{ color: 'white' }}
                            autoCapitalize={'none'}
                            value={values.username}
                            autoFocus={true}
                          />
                          <Text style={styles.errorStyle}>{errors.username}</Text>
                        </Item>

                        <Item>
                          <Input
                           onChangeText={handleChange('password')}
                           onBlur={handleBlur('password')}
                           style={{ color: 'white' }}
                            secureTextEntry={true}
                            placeholder="Şifre"
                            value={values.password} />
                            <Text style={styles.errorStyle}>{errors.password}</Text>

                        </Item>

                        <Button style={{ alignSelf: 'center', marginTop: 20, padding: 10 }} warning
                          block
                          onPress={handleSubmit}
                        >
                          <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }} > GİRİŞ YAP </Text>
                        </Button>


                        <View>
                          <Text
                            style={{ textAlign: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', color: '#999', marginTop: 150 }}
                            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('FSignup')}
                          >Henüz üye değilseniz. Buradan Kayıt Olun</Text>
                        </View>

                      </Form>
                    )}
                  </Formik>
              }
            </Content>

          </Container>
        </View>
     
      </ScrollView>





    );

  };
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bigContainer: {
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    flex: 1,

  },
  containerx: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width:'100%'
  },

  loginText: {
    color: '#c79816',
    fontSize: 20,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    margin: 7,
    fontWeight: "700"
  },
  emptyCont: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 100,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  errorStyle: {
 
    fontSize: 15,
    color: 'red'
},



});
```

Tried keyboardAvoidingView element in react native but i can not get a good result
Could you help me please?

Comment: Please provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I took some time modifying your code so I can run it, but it did not display the issue. I don't want to further modify your code, as it will take too much time. Please provide an example where we can simply copy/paste the code, install the imported dependencies, and then run the app.

Answer (score 0):

you have to manually close it in this case either put the input `autoFocus` to `false` or use the manual react-native `Keyboard` handler like below:

```
import {Keyboard} from 'react-native'
```

Now when the component mounts we will close the keyboard.

```
componentDidMount(){
Keyboard.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on the significance of your code, and why it solves the issue